# VB.NET openFileDialog crash

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress

I am having issues with calling openFileDialog on button click.

Relevant code:

```
   Private Sub MemoCp_ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As ButtonPressedEventArgs) Handles MemoCp.ButtonClick
        Dim Editor As ButtonEdit = CType(sender, ButtonEdit)
        Dim Button As EditorButton = e.Button
        If Editor.Properties.Buttons.IndexOf(e.Button).ToString() = 1 Then
            Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
                ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
                ofd.FileName = ""
                ofd.ShowHelp = True
                ofd.ShowDialog() <-- Program crashes here
                TryCast(sender, ButtonEdit).EditValue = ofd.FileName
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub
```

I have a form with 2 checkboxes. When I don't select any check box and click the button, it works perfectly, but if i select the checkboxes beforehand and click the button, I get this error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x769F1DF3 (shell32.dll) in Unos.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000A.
```

With this call Stack:

```
    shell32.dll!CExplorerBrowser::Advise()  Unknown
    comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::_CreateExplorerBrowser()    Unknown
    comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::_InitOpenSaveDialog(struct HWND__ *)    Unknown
    comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::s_OpenSaveDlgProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)   Unknown
    user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()   Unknown
    user32.dll!UserCallDlgProcCheckWow()    Unknown
    user32.dll!DefDlgProcWorker()   Unknown
    user32.dll!_DefDlgProcW@16()    Unknown
    user32.dll!__InternalCallWinProc@20()   Unknown
    user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
    user32.dll!DispatchClientMessage()  Unknown
    user32.dll!___fnDWORD@4()   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()    Unknown
    user32.dll!InternalCreateDialog()   Unknown
    user32.dll!InternalDialogBox()  Unknown
    user32.dll!_DialogBoxIndirectParamAorW@24() Unknown
    user32.dll!_DialogBoxIndirectParamW@20()    Unknown
    comdlg32.dll!CFileOpenSave::Show(struct HWND__ *)   Unknown
    comdlg32.dll!_InvokeNewFileOpenSave(struct IFileDialog *,unsigned short,struct HWND__ *,struct _OFNINITINFO *,struct HWND__ *)  Unknown
    comdlg32.dll!_CreateNewFileOpenSaveInProc(unsigned short,struct HWND__ *,struct _OFNINITINFO *) Unknown
    comdlg32.dll!NewGetFileName(struct OPENFILEINFO *,int)  Unknown
    comdlg32.dll!_GetFileName@8()   Unknown
    comdlg32.dll!_GetOpenFileNameW@4()  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll!65f0b4f0()  Unknown
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, native debugger attempting to walk managed call stack]   Unknown
    [External Code] 
>   Unos.exe!Unos.FormUnos.MemoCp_ButtonClick(Object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e) Line 611 Basic
    [External Code]
```

I am struggling to fix this for 5 days, if you could help me solve it I would be very grateful!
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I shortened the form code as much as I could so that the problem still occurs. Here is the entire code of the shortened version:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Text
Imports DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls

Partial Public Class Form1
    Shared Sub New()
        DevExpress.UserSkins.BonusSkins.Register()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Drzave_LookUp()
    End Sub
    Public Sub Drzave_LookUp()


        Dim sqlDrzave As String = "Select Drzave.SifraDrzave, Drzave.Naziv, Drzave.OZNAKA " &
                                " FROM Drzave INNER JOIN Kupci On Drzave.SifraDrzave = Kupci.Drzava " &
                                            " GROUP BY Drzave.SifraDrzave, Drzave.Naziv, Drzave.OZNAKA " &
                                            " ORDER BY Drzave.SifraDrzave "



        Dim DrzaveAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlDrzave, cn)
        Dim dsKupci As DataSet = New DataSet
        DrzaveAdapter.Fill(dsKupci, "Drzave")

        SearchLookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = dsKupci.Tables("Drzave")
        SearchLookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Naziv"
        SearchLookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "Naziv"
        SearchLookUpEdit1.Properties.BestFitMode = BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup
        SearchLookUpEdit1.Properties.PopulateViewColumns()


    End Sub
    Private Sub SearchLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchLookUpEdit1.EditValueChanged
        Objekti_LookUp(SearchLookUpEdit1.EditValue)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Objekti_LookUp(ByVal drzava As String)

        Dim sqlObjekti As String = "SELECT Objekti.SifraObjekta, Objekti.Naziv, Objekti.Adresa, Objekti.Mesto, Objekti.Instalater, Objekti.Drzava " &
                                    " FROM Objekti " &
                                    " WHERE (((Objekti.Drzava)='" & drzava & "')) "

        Dim ObjektiAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlObjekti, cn)
        Dim dsObjekti As DataSet = New DataSet
        ObjektiAdapter.Fill(dsObjekti, "Objekti")

        SearchLookUpEdit2.Properties.DataSource = dsObjekti.Tables("Objekti")
        SearchLookUpEdit2.Properties.DisplayMember = "SifraObjekta"
        SearchLookUpEdit2.Properties.ValueMember = "SifraObjekta"
        SearchLookUpEdit2.Properties.BestFitMode = BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup
        SearchLookUpEdit2.Properties.PopulateViewColumns()

    End Sub
    Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
        Dim SelectedFilePath As String = ""
        Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
            ofd.InitialDirectory = "Z:\"
            ofd.FileName = ""
            ofd.ShowHelp = True
            If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then <-- Program crashes here
                SelectedFilePath = ofd.FileName
            End If
        End Using
        Debug.Print(SelectedFilePath)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: By default, users don't have permissions for files in the root of the C:\ drive. This has been true since at least 2002. Also, there's no guarantee you even have a C:\ drive. You can setup a drive to be D: or most other letters and install Windows there if you know what you're doing.

Comment: But it works fine if the first thing I do when I open the form is click the button, it opens it without error at C:\. The error happens if I click on the checkboxes before clicking on the button (that calls openFileDialog()). The error still happens if I do change from C to D unfortunately.

Comment: Is there any code for check_changed event?

Comment: Hi, I edited the original post I added the entire (shortened) code. Is this fine?

Comment: Went to bed, coming back now and looking at the edit, and this is very much **not okay**: `" WHERE (((Objekti.Drzava)='" & drzava & "')) "`. It's called SQL injection and it's a _big deal_. Don't do that!

Comment: A) What is this "any check box " of which you speak? 2) `ofd.InitialDirectory = "Z:\"` hmmm,... iii) If the line `ofd.InitialDirectory = "Z:\"` is removed, does it still crash? As in, does the drive "Z:" exist for the account the program is running under?

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine without whatever 3rd party button you are using. Your problem is probably on the line following the one you indicated. Your problem is not with the `OpenFileDialog`. Ask a new question that explains what the `ButtonEdit` and `EditorButton` are.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SelectedFilePath As String = ""
    Using ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        ofd.FileName = ""
        ofd.ShowHelp = True
        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            SelectedFilePath = ofd.FileName
        End If
    End Using
    Debug.Print(SelectedFilePath)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I edited the original question and added additional code, hope it can help.

Comment: Works for me. Just tested.